# React Native: Dynamically render components using a variable instead of the component name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, hybrid-mobile-app, react-component

I need help trying to dynamically return/render a custom component in my react native app.

**My goal is to use a variable to render a component, instead of that component's original name.**

In my react native code, I have 4 "character" components which take the exact same props. Any one of these might need to be rendered based on my user's interaction, so I want to clean up my code by only writing the component block once.

My problem is that to make this work right now I have a switch/case block taking the prop and returning the correct component. This means I have a lot of repeating code which I'd like to remove, but I keep getting the same error:

> View config getter callback for component [MY COMPONENT NAME] must be a function (received 'undefined')

My full code is below, what am I doing wrong?

```js
import React, { } from 'react';
import {
  View,
} from "react-native";

// My custom components
import Larry from './characters/larry';
import Jane from './characters/jane';
import Reginald from './characters/reginald';
import Amy from './characters/amy';

const CharacterFactory = (props) => {

  // I WANT TO DO IT THIS WAY BUT IT DOES NOT WORK AND RESULTS IN AN ERROR:
  // View config getter callback for component 'Larry' must be a function (received 'undefined')
  const FactoryOutput = props.character;
  return (
    <FactoryOutput
      top={props.top}
      bottom={props.bottom}
      shoes={props.shoes}
    />
  );

  // THIS APPROACH WORKS BUT IT IS TOO LONG AND INEFFICIENT AS MORE CHARACTERS GET ADDED
  switch (props.character) {
    case 'Larry':
      return (
        <Larry
          top={props.top}
          bottom={props.bottom}
          shoes={props.shoes}
        />
      );
      break;
      
    case 'Jane':
      return (
        <Jane
          top={props.top}
          bottom={props.bottom}
          shoes={props.shoes}
        />
      );
      break;
      
    case 'Reginald':
      return (
        <Reginald
          top={props.top}
          bottom={props.bottom}
          shoes={props.shoes}
        />
      );
      break;
      
    case 'Amy':
      return (
        <Amy
          top={props.top}
          bottom={props.bottom}
          shoes={props.shoes}
        />
      );
      break;

    default:
      break;
  }
}

export default CharacterFactory;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP here, I figured it out and wanted to leave the answer here for future readers.

First you have to create a const object of all imported components that you want to dynamically render. This has to be outside of the main component block.

```
const characters = {
  Larry,
  Jane,
  Reginald,
  Amy,
};
```

Then inside your main component, you create a const for your target import by referencing the array you created earlier.

```
const FactoryOutput = characters[props.character];
```

And finally you can write a single block of code which will dynamically render the imported component based on a prop value. No more switch/case statements.

```
<FactoryOutput
  top={props.top}
  bottom={props.bottom}
  shoes={props.shoes}
/>
```

Here's the original code modified with the solution:

```js
import React, {} from 'react';
import {
  View,
} from "react-native";

// My custom components
import Larry from './characters/larry';
import Jane from './characters/jane';
import Reginald from './characters/reginald';
import Amy from './characters/amy';

const characters = {
  Larry,
  Jane,
  Reginald,
  Amy,
};

const CharacterFactory = (props) => {

  const FactoryOutput = characters[props.character];
  
  return (
    <FactoryOutput
      top={props.top}
      bottom={props.bottom}
      shoes={props.shoes}
    />
  );
}

export default CharacterFactory;
```

Comment: what if you have different types of components with different props accepted?